# Как создать класс динамического создания графиков?

Tags: c++, qt, qchartview

Начал создавать класс динамического создания графиков и наткнулся на ошибки , что я делаю не так ?

заголовочный QChart подключен в кумейке

```
#ifndef QDYNAMICCHART_H
#define QDYNAMICCHART_H

#include <QChart>


class QDynamicChart: public QChart
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QDynamicChart(QChart *parent = 0);

    ~QDynamicChart();

    static int ResID;   // Статическая переменная, счетчик номеров графика
    int getID();        // Функция для возврата локального номера графика


public slots:

private:
    int ChartID = 0;   // Локальная переменная, номер графика
};

#endif // QDYNAMICCHART_H
```

ошибки

```
qdynamicchart.h:14:29: Unknown class name 'QChart'; did you mean 'QChar'? (fix available)
:2089:1: note: 'QChar' declared here
change 'QChart' to 'QChar'

qdynamicchart.h:18:28: Unknown type name 'QChart'; did you mean 'QChar'? (fix available)
qchar.h:75:21: 'QChar' declared here
change 'QChart' to 'QChar'
```

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcharts-index.html#building-with-qmake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Другой заголовочный нужон    #include "QtCharts"

**.h**

```
#ifndef QDYNAMICCHART_H
#define QDYNAMICCHART_H

//#include <QChart>
//#include <QtCharts/QChartGlobal>

#include <QtCharts>

class QDynamicChart: public QChart
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QDynamicChart(QChart *parent = 0);

    ~QDynamicChart();

    static int ResID;   // Статическая переменная, счетчик номеров графика
    int getID();        // Функция для возврата локального номера графика


public slots:

private:
    int ChartID = 0;   // Локальная переменная, номер графика
};

#endif // QDYNAMICCHART_H
```

**.cpp**

```
#include "qdynamicchart.h"


QDynamicChart::QDynamicChart(QChart *parent) :
    QChart(parent)
{
    ResID++;            // Увеличение счетчика на единицу
    ChartID = ResID;   /* Присвоение кнопке номера, по которому будет производиться
                         * дальнейшая работа с кнопок
                         * */
}

QDynamicChart::~QDynamicChart()
{

}
/* Метод для возврата значения номера кнопки
 * */
int QDynamicChart::getID()
{
    return ChartID;
}

/* Инициализация статической переменной класса.
 * Статическая переменная класса должна инициализироваться в обязательном порядке
 * */
int QDynamicChart::ResID = 0;
```